# Apt-get refuses to stop trying to install Acroreader

Tags: apt, dpkg, synaptic

I'm using Mint 13 if that matters. And I'm new.

Anyway, I tried installing Adobe Reader 9 using their installer from:

http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=10&platform=Unix

It got stuck when on a line that said something about setting up icons. There was no CPU usage for about an hour, so I killed the process.

Of course, running `apt-get again` (to install another program) gives me a lock error. So after rebooting to unlock, I use this command:

```
sudo dpkg -a --configure
```

and then...

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

... as instructed by similar questions on the "AskUbuntu" forum. However, it once again gets stuck at an installation step and gives me this line:

> Setting up acroread (9.4.7-1oneiric1) ...

...which I then kill. I tried using Synaptic to mark the incomplete acroread install for deletion, but it gets hung up on another line. It says something about a plugin being invalid if I recall correctly.

I want to tell apt-get to just stop trying to install acroread every time I use the command. Any ideas?

Comment: Happens what if you `apt-get remove acroread`?

Answer (score 6):

Try `apt-get purge acroread` or `dpkg --purge acroread`.

If neither of these work first time, edit `/var/lib/dpkg/info/acroread.postinst` and add `exit 0` as the second line of the script (immediately after the `#!` line).

Then run `dpkg --configure acroread`.  This will allow the package configuration to complete (without doing anything, so it's not really completely installed and configured) so apt-get won't try to reconfigure it again.

You should now be able to purge the `acroread` package.